# Using Countifs formula when the data is on different rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with data about customer rejections, arranged so:

```
         Col1            Col2            Col3     

Row1   Customer      Rejection Reason

Row2                                    Vendor
```

What I would like to do is use a COUNTIFS formula to determine which vendors where rejected for which reason. The problem is the vendor is listed on a separate row from the rejection reason so my typical method of using a COUNTIFS formula does not work. Is there some sort of workaround that will prevent me from having to rearrange the data so that everything is on the same row?

I appreciate any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: I encourage you to fix the data. [This post](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/fill-the-empty-cells-left-by-pivot-table-row-fields/) shows how to fill in blanks with the value in the row below, and should be useful (ignore that it's about pivot tables, the concept is the same). Once that is done, I strongly encourage you to consider creating a pivot table - instead of using `COUNTIF`. Pivot tables are made for this kind of task.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thank you for the reply and the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly support @Doug's advice but does seem to be feasible with COUNTIFS with current layout, eg:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C18,"="&D1,B1:B17,"="&E1)
```

where D1 is the Vendor option and E1 the Rejection Reason option (assuming Col1 is A, etc.)

Comment: Thanks pnuts, this will help I think!